# Can I use Javascript to detect whether a checkbox has been checked?

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

I'm trying to use Javascript to detect whether a checkbox has been checked. My plan is to allow the user to select the checkbox in order to mark a letter as printed and then use Ajax to update the database.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
<label for="printed">Printed</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="8200" id="8200" value="P" onclick="checked(this.id);" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checked(id) {
    var remember = document.getElementById(id);
    if (remember.checked){
      alert("checked");
    }else{
      alert("You didn't check it!");
    }
  }
</script>
```

All I get in return is an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function from Google Chrome and checked is not a function from Firefox.`

Comment: is a JQuery solution ok?

Comment: There is something missing in your code.

Comment: yeah I'm happy to use jQuery although not had any luck with it so far...

Comment: You want to know if the element has been clicked at all (and potentially reset to its default state), or whether the element's state has been changed *from* its default?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a different name to your javascript method, as the boolean checked field of the input just hides the one you've defined...

Comment: Yep... rename it ischecked or similar and update the onclick event

Comment: perfect! :) thought it might be something simple, i will accept this in 8 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the name of the javascript method.

HTML:

```
<label for="printed">Printed</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="8200" id="8200" value="P" onclick="isChecked(this.id);" />
```

JS:

```
   function isChecked(id) {
        var remember = document.getElementById(id);
        if (remember.checked){
            alert("checked");
        }else{
            alert("You didn't check it!");
        }
    }
```

Look at this JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6dx6A/39/

Answer (score 1):

Just simply change your function name you are using  as "checked(this.id)". I've tried checked1(this.id). It worked

Answer (score 1):

You can change the function name to get the answer as follows. It worked for me

```
function IsChecked(id)
{
    var remember = document.getElementById(id);
    if (remember.checked){
       alert("checked");
    }else{
       alert("You didn't check it!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you got a different jQuery solution I'm not happy with, I'll give you my jQuery solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="8200" id="theid" value="P" />

// 8200 isn't a valid id in HTML4, it can't start with a number
$('#theid').change(function(){
    if (this.checked)
        alert('checked');
    else
        alert('unchecked');
});
```

Comment: I disagree, this would require you to write the JQuery function for every checkbox you wanted to apply it to. Did you not see my note of adding a classname?

Comment: @PastorBones. He didn't mention he has more than one checkbox, why should I use a class selector? And let's say he has more than one, who said the change handling should be the same for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have in a JQuery solution and will work for every checkbox on the page (add a class to the selector to be able to apply this to only certain checkboxes)

```
$(function(){
  var remember;
  $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    remember = $(this).attr('id');

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      // Checkbox is checked

    } else {
      // Checkbox is NOT checked

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: 1) But there is no jQuery tag here. 2) you use jQuery way too much here. 3) adding more than id to a selector makes it inefficient. Sorry for picking on you.

Comment: in his defence i said i was open to a jquery solution

Comment: @gdoron I use too much JQuery? LOL wtf? You use too many letters in your sentences...

Comment: @jampez77. If you want a jQuery solution you can [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13377444/601179)